# Sorting an Excel spreadsheet based on multiple columns using Groovy in SoapUI

Tags: excel, groovy, apache-poi, soapui

I've managed to sort the rows in my Excel file based on a column (in either ascending or descending order) using the following Groovy code in SoapUI :

```
        List<Row> rows = Lists.newArrayList(sheet.rowIterator())
        //sort rows in the temp
        def sortedRows = rows.tail().sort({ row -> row.getCell(colNum).getStringCellValue() })
        if (sortOrder == 1)
        {
            sortedRows = sortedRows.reverse() //Descending order instead
        }
```

Now I need to add another column for sorting to that so that the rows will be ordered first by Column A then by Column B for example.  I'm not sure the inherent sort function for the List type would be able to do that.  Any suggestions.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call `List.sort` with custom comparator. Like this one (code in Java)

```
Comparator.comparing(row -> row.getCell(colNum1).getStringCellValue())
          .thenComparing(row -> row.getCell(colNum2).getStringCellValue())
```

Comment: Tried using the Comparator in Groovy and all it does is throw up errors no matter what I try to pass in to it which was why I went back to the simple List.sort

Comment: When I change the code to use :
 ```def sortedRows = rows.tail().sort(Comparator.comparing( row -> row.getCell(colNum).getStringCellValue() ))```, 
it throws up an error : ```Script12.groovy: 35: unexpected token: -> @ line 35, column 69. ort(Comparator.comparing( row -> row.get ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: -> @ line 35, column 69.```

Comment: It's Java code, not Groovy. You should convert it properly, at least add `{...}`.

Comment: Ok, just updated that and now it returns a NULL sortedRows object such that attempting to reverse its order using the .reverse() cause a java.lang.NullPointerException